# Why can't a Nazir finish his Nezirut by reciting Korbanot?

Tags: nozir, korbanos-ketores-prayers

I came across an interesting article ([Source for Reading Korbanot in place of actual sacrifice](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-13-03/)) that talks about how we fulfill the practice of korbanot nowadays by reading passages about korbanot.
So, I was wondering, why wouldn't it be possible for a Nazir to finish his nezirut vow by reciting Korbanot passages?

Answer (score 1):

Rambam (הלכות נזירות - פרק שני) discusses this scenario - of being a Nazir nowadays, and states:

> מִי שֶׁנָּדַר בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ כּוֹפִין אוֹתוֹ לַעֲלוֹת לְאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל וְלִהְיוֹת נוֹהֵג שָׁם נְזִירוּת עַד שֶׁיָּמוּת אוֹ עַד שֶׁיִּבָּנֶה הַמִּקְדָּשׁ וְיָבִיא קָרְבְּנוֹתָיו בִּמְלֹאת יְמֵי נִזְרוֹ:‏

> One who makes a vow to become a Nazir nowadays... remains a Nazir until he dies or until the Mikdash is rebuilt.

If, by reciting the relevant passages he would be absolved of his Nazir status, Rambam would have said so.

Comment: This answers that it isn't possible, but the question asked "why wouldn't it be possible"